# Desktop can't delete file because thunar was replaced by nautilus (Xubuntu 12.04)

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, xubuntu, thunar

My problem is really simple:

I've replaced Thunar with Nautilus in my Xubuntu 12.04 installation (64 Bit); I removed Thunar completely. Everything works fine in the computer except for the desktop: If I try to delete a file that is in the desktop for example, The attempt fails complaining of Thunar not being installed on the system. If I reinstall thunar everything works as expected, but I don't want to keep thunar on the system. How to Fix This?

Thanks!

Comment: perhaps you can explain how you replaced thunar with nautilus "completely" - need this information to see if we can reproduce your issue.  Also - are you using nautilus to manage your desktop now? `nautilus --no-desktop` I think.

Comment: "sudo apt-get remove thunar && sudo apt-get install nautilus" that was what I did, everything went well, except for this thing.

Answer (score 2):

Research indicates that there are issues between Thunar and Nautilus.

[Replacing Thunar with Nautilus?](http://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=6401):

> The desktop component doesn't play well yet with the filemanager because it is using the dbus interface of thunar directly.

[Thunar File Manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/thunar/):

> It does not play nice (at all) when copying out of it's own Thunar window and into the Nautilus window.

My own experience is that I cannot cut/copy/drag files directly from the desktop to a Nautilus window.  I get the following 2 errors:

```
Error while moving "New Folder ".
There was an error moving the file into /home/****/From Desktop.
Error moving file: No such file or directory

Error while moving.
There was an error getting information about "".
Operation not supported
```

I get exactly the same errors when attempting to copy/cut/drag from a Thunar window to a Nautilus window.

Workarounds:

1. Use the Thunar file manager when working directly with the desktop (cut/copy/drag)
2. Do all of your file operations from within Nautilus itself

So even if Thunar has been completely removed from the system, you should still be able use workaround #2.

Applies to:

- Xubuntu 12.04
- Nautilus 3.4.2
- Thunar 1.2.3

Answer (score -1):

Try uninstalling the `xubuntu-default-settings` package. That did it for me.

You can also get rid of `parole` (the Xfce movie player) and `leafpad` and `mousepad` (Xfce text editors) and use `totem` and `gedit` instead.

Comment: Sorry, it turns out my desktop is actually still managed by Thunar. I'm looking for a solution to the same problem: how can I set xfce4's desktop file manager to Nautilus?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: I think I have it working now. Steps taken were: 1) Open Settings>Session and Startup, on Sessions tab set "Xfdesktop" to "Never" and click save session. On Application autostart tab add an autostarter for the command "nautilus -n". 2)Install "gnome-tweak-tool" and in the desktop tab, turn on "Trash Icon visible on the desktop". Now when I click on anything including trash on the desktop, it is handled by Nautilus. Hope that helps!

Comment: @M-J That (your comment) doesn't work for me. No desktop shows up if I do that. And running gnome-tweak-tool (thru Terminal Emulator) shows this error message: `WARNING : Shell not installed or running - (gnome-tweak-tool:1884): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings' is not installed - Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)`.